# Plugin for automatic database backup?

Tags: plugins, backup

Is there a reliable plugin that I could use to automatically backup the WP database? **It's really important that it's just the database and not the files.**

I'd like it to automatically download a copy of the database and store it on my computer in a specified file.

Is there one out there that could do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[BackWPup](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/backwpup/) has a lot of flexibility in timing, what to backup (down to the DB table level), and it can store to DropBox which would put it on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Backup Buddy is my absolute favorite.
Features:

- db only backups
- full backups
- migration tool
- scheduled backups to email or remote server
- malware inspection

http://pluginbuddy.com/purchase/backupbuddy/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all in one plugin for WordPress backup, deliver and restore operations, then I would recommend you to take a look at [HotBackup](http://codecanyon.net/item/hot-backup-manager/1910588?ref=straightforward) plugin. I could enable database backup only and connect it to your Dropbox account. Then backups will be created by a schedule and automatically uploads to your Dropbox account and then to your pc.

Answer (score -1):

[Useful Information](http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2010/05/wordpress-backup-services/). Just go through the link & you will get lot of details about backup plugin and [more useful](http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/3-ways-to-automatically-backup-wordpress-blog-database-files/) I submitted for you

Comment: External link(s) alone doesn't make a good answer. Please include at least summary of information which can be found at a link.

Comment: @:Rarst: Thanks for your advice.i'll do it in upcoming days.